# Using javascript to create InfoPath form in a SharePoint library

Tags: document-library, infopath, javascript

Are there javascript / javascript framework that allows developer to create InfoPath Form in a SharePoint Library?

Suppose there is a SharePoint Library called 'Finance Application'. When a user click the [New] Button, it will open a web-based InfoPath form for the user to fill in.

However, I was wondering if it is possible to use Javascript / Javascript framework to create or populate the infopath form so that the user did not need to click the [New] button?

I am open to other choice of programming language beside Javascript that can do the above. However, one thing to note is that the developer cannot develop the website on the server that have the SharePoint 2007 installed.

Comment: Why don't you just link to the NewForm? Not really sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @KitMenke, Actually I am trying to use javascript coding to perform that function.

Answer (score 1):

You create an aspx **webpart** page in Sharepoint Designer 2010: Team Site > **Site** tab on ribbon > **Web Part Page**  button > choose one of layouts. In created aspx page, click on ribbon under **Insert** tab, click **Web Part** button > **More Web Parts...** > **Infopath Form Web Part** under **Forms** section.

And then configure its connection with other Web Parts on this page, Lists or Libraries in **Infopath Form Web Part** properties

The same is possible to do through web browser.

Note that you should have created Infopath form in Infopath Desogner 2010 for corresponding a list or a library.

You cannot create Infopath forms in Javascript or Javascript Framework or even in Sharepoint Designer. The external frameworks. programs  or servicesIt can only use and configure the already existing Infopath forms created in Infopath Designer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `lists.asmx` web service to submit your form data ?

Comment: Ian, do you have links to show how to go about using the lists.asmx web service to fill in the form before-hand for the user?

Comment: If you google for jQuery sharepoint webservices there are a few javascript libraries out there which might be useful.